# Using Loops to Simplify Python Dictonaries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm working on teaching myself Python and I've been using Codecademy as a tool for that. I've understood the basic premise of writing in certain keys to dictionaries, but I realized adding keys to dictionaries using loops would be easier, especially if you had to modify your code later on, and each dictionary has identical values. However, I cannot get my code to return the values I want:

```
students = {"lloyd" : [], "alice" : [], "tyler" : []}

for student in students:
    student = {
        "name" : [], 
        "homework" : [], 
        "quizzes" : [], 
        "tests" : []
    }

print students
```

But this returns:

```
{'tyler': [], 'lloyd': [], 'alice': []}
None
```

How would I set this up, so that... it... actually worked, and I had "name", "homework", "test", and "quiz" all under the students' names?

Comment: Your code doesn't change the contents of the `students` dictionary, it just assigns a whole other dictionary to a copy of each key it finds in it which doesn't accomplish andything — so that explains the first line of the output. Not sure where the second line with `None` on it is coming from...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you aren't `return`ing anything. Second, you're overwriting the 'student' variable and never saving the value you've created. You should keep track, or modify the dict as you go:

```
students = {"lloyd" : [], "alice" : [], "tyler" : []}

for student in students:
    students[student] = {  # Notice the change here
        "name" : [], 
        "homework" : [], 
        "quizzes" : [], 
        "tests" : []
    }

print students
```

Python supports classes for this sort of thing, too, though you may not have gotten to that part of your tutorials yet:

```
class Student: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.tests = []
        self.quizzes = []
        self.name = ""
        self.homework = []
```

And then you can have certain behaviors associated with a Student:

```
    def hw_average(self): 
        return sum(self.homework)/len(self.homework) # divide by zero if no homework, so don't actually do this.
```

And then you can interact with Students:

```
jeff = Student()
jeff.name = "Jeff"
jeff.homework = [85, 92, 61, 78]
jeff.hw_average()  # 79
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are reassigning the `student` variable in the loop, but the original dictionary remains unchanged.
If you want to use dicts for this, the canonical way to do this would be to generate the dict from a template using a factory function, then use it to in the creation of your students dictionary.

```
def make_student(name)
   return  {
    "name" : name,
    "homework" : [],
    "quizzes" : [],
    "tests" : []
   }

students = {name : make_student(name) for name in ['lloyd', 'alice' 'tyler']}
print(students)
```

That being said it would be better still to make a class (per the other answer).